# RPI 4 — need libcrypto.so.1.0.0 to compile and run

Tags: shared-libraries

I am trying to compile some c++ source code I obtained from a client. I managed to include all the dynamic libraries and running `g++ <args> -o bin/thin <path to main.cpp>` yields the following output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./Libraries/Linux/ThinLayer/armv7l/libThinLayer.so.1.0.1: invalid string offset 1358 >= 183 for section `.strtab'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.1.0.0, needed by ./Libraries/Linux/ThinLayer/armv7l/libThinLayer.so.1.0.1, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

ldd bin/thin
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0xbea32000)
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so (0xb6ebc000)
    libThinLayer.so.1 => /home/pi/G2KSDK4.1/Libraries/Linux/ThinLayer/armv7l/libThinLayer.so.1 (0xb6ea5000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6d5e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6cdc000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6caf000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6b61000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
    librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0xb6b4a000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6ed1000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6b20000)
```

So `libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found` shows that the library is missing. As far as I know until now, this library is part of the `openssl` package, and

```
ldconfig -p | grep -i libcrypto
    libcrypto.so.1.1 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

shows that the package is actually installed.

Is it possible to compile the code using an older version of libcrypto without downgrading the whole package? I not, how can I downgrade this package?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this properly:

1. Ask the client to send you the missing libraries. I think the modern way of doing so is packaging the app in a Docker container.
2. Ask the client to built their libraries against a given Raspbian release, and then install and use that release.
3. Ask the client to provide you the source code so that you can build all the libraries you need on any system.

Spoofing missing libraries using symlinks will only work if not a single function you use actually changed its prototype (number, type and order of arguments) between 1.0.0 and 1.1. Any attempt to execute a non-compatible function will result in a crash in the best case, and a hard-to-find bug or an open vulnerability in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> libThinLayer.so.1.0.1: invalid string offset 1358 >= 183 for section `.strtab'
> ```

Is this something you built? Presumably not if it's the same thing that's linked to a non-existent lib. It may turn into a problem for you if you get everything built -- but it isn't the cause of this one.  This is:

```
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
               ^^^
ldconfig -p | grep -i libcrypto
    libcrypto.so.1.1 (libc6,hard-float)
                 ^^^
```

The installed version is 1.1 whereas `libThinLayer` was linked to 1.0.  You could try adding a symlink of `1.0.0` to `1.1` in an out of tree location, or copy it under the different name.  You then need `-L` when building to get the linker to look in that location.

```
mkdir lib
ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.1 lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
export LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/lib/:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

You could just do it directly in `/usr/lib/arm-linux...` instead and run `ldconfig` but the other way seems a bit safer.  This is part of openSSL.

Chances are that will work -- although the fact that a `1.0` symlink doesn't exist and that the .so was linked to `1.0.0` specifically implies some compatibility issue, it may also just be a quirk.

Comment: libThinLayer.so is part of the software I obtained from the client. I will try the idea the symlink, sound like a lovely hack :)

Comment: I have tried to create a symlink and link it. So the compile error is gone, but trying to run the program yields the same error, that libcrypto.so.1.0.0 is missing. I would be really glad if you could provide an example about where to place the symlink and how to use g++.

Comment: I've edited one in above.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://ftp.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.0/openssl-1.0.0k.tar.gz
tar xvf  openssl-1.0.0k.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.0k
```

Create file "openssl.ld" in the current folder with the content below:

```
OPENSSL_1.0.0 {
    global:
    *;
};
```

and run the next commands:

```
./config shared --prefix=$HOME/Programme/openssl --openssldir=$HOME/Programme/ssl -Wl,--version-script=openssl.ld -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
make
sudo make install_sw
sudo ldconfig
ldd $HOME/Programme/openssl/bin/openssl
sudo cp $HOME/Programme/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so /usr/local/lib
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so
sudo ldconfig
```

The libraries for compiling:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install libtool autoconf build-essential pkg-config automake tcsh
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).